# How can an intransitive verb have 'objects' and 'complements'?

Tags: verbs, objects, predicate, object-complements

> [[Source:]](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm#complement) The following description of predicates comes from
>   *The Longman Handbook for Writers and Readers* (examples our own):
>
> With an **intransitive** verb, **`objects`** and **`complements`** are included in the predicate.
>   (The glacier is melting.)
>   With a **transitive** verb, **objects** and **object complements** are said to be part of the predicate.
>   (The slow moving glacier wiped out an entire forest. It gave the villagers a lot of problems.)
>   [With a **linking verb**, the subject is connected to a **subject complement**.](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm)
>   (The mayor doesn't feel good.)

By definition, intransitive verbs lack a direct object, but because [indirect object => direct object](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/225379/50720), they lack an indirect object too. So what does the above mean by **`objects`** and **`complements`** ?

Comment: You can learn about intransitive verbs that take complements here: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~xtag/tech-report/node29.html

Comment: Intransitive verbs don't have objects.  But many verbs that are normally used intransitively can also be used transitively: "He died a painful death."

Comment: I really have no idea what that paragraph is trying to say. I can only assume that they made some mistake in transcribing it . . .

Comment: Don't "included in the predicate" and "said to be part of the predicate" mean the same thing? I agree with @ruakh, there's something not quite right about that paragraph, although snailboat is also right that normally intransitive verbs can sometimes be used transitively.

Comment: I strongly recommend focusing on grammar terminology when you are at higher levels so when you ask a question others can figure out what you're asking. Also grammarians have different ideas about calling different parts in a sentence. You can even see this in dictionaries when they try to assign a part of speech to a word e.g. _all_ is also considered to be an adjective in Merriam Webster while in LDOCE it's definitely not classified as an adjectives. Anyway I hope you can get your answer here. –

Comment: The problem is solved! Instead of **complements**, perhaps an intransitive verb can take **Complementizers!** [link](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html)

Comment: No, intransitive verbs (sometimes) take complements.

Answer (score 1):

The initial page actually has anchor links for each word, making it easy to see what the web page is trying to convey.

> With an **intransitive verb**, *objects* and *complements* are included in the predicate. (The glacier *is melting*.)

The *objects* word links to the ***Direct and Indirect Objects*** and thus refers to either or both direct objects and indirect objects. This is further a nod to both intransitive verbs, which don't require either, and ditransitive verbs, which can take both at once.

The *complements* word links to the ***Complements*** section and thus refers to words or phrases that complete the sense of a subject, object, or verb.

So, let's bring that back to the sentence and its accompanying example:

- Not only is the glacier the subject in action (the glacier melts), but also receives said action (the glacier is being melted as a result of its melting).
- The word *melting* is a complement that completes the sense of the verb *is* here, and thus is a verb complement.

In your defense, the page isn't terribly well organized and, as Yuri points out in her comment, suffers from inconsistent nomenclature. I'm pretty sure that you're neither the first nor the last person to be confused by that web page (yeah, it was confusing me for a while too).